# How to run two same kind of daemons on a single linux machine

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, daemons

In Ubuntu 14.04 or Debian Wheezy, Can I run two daemons of same type in a single machine?

I already tried to do that, by creating separate config files under /etc/init.d/ , /usr/bin/, Created separate symbolic links under /etc/rc[0-6].d/ for /etc/init.d/daemon.

Can you suggest any other way to run, possibly succeeded ways.

I am trying this link, for installation https://raw.githubusercontent.com/weaved/installer/master/weaved_installer.raspbian

Thanks